# Amazon SP API Feeds API processing report: Invalid product type

Tags: python, amazon-product-api, amazon-selling-partner-api

I have been working with the feeds API. I have been able to create a feed document, encrypt and upload a payload to the returned URL, create the feed, and then check its status. Once status reaches the `DONE` state, I was also able to get the processing report: The processing report looks like this:

```
{
  "header": {
    "sellerId": "A1HGLY0OQBKE5U",
    "version": "2.0",
    "feedId": "50042018828"
  },
  "issues": [
    {
      "messageId": 1,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 2,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 3,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 4,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 5,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 6,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 7,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 8,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 9,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 10,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 11,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 12,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 13,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 14,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 15,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 16,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 17,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 18,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    },
    {
      "messageId": 19,
      "code": "4000003",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
    }
  ],
  "summary": {
    "errors": 19,
    "warnings": 0,
    "messagesProcessed": 19,
    "messagesAccepted": 0,
    "messagesInvalid": 19
  }
}
```

The Payload was this:

```
{
  "header": {
    "sellerId": "A1HGLY0OQBKE5U",
    "version": "2.0"
  },
  "messages": [
    {
      "messageId": 1,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "Awesome Bronze Car",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "sk77"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 2,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "Sleek Steel Chair",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "sk80"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 3,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "Aerodynamic Iron Gloves",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "sk81"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 4,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "Sleek Copper Clock",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "sk86"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 5,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "Mediocre Plastic Wallet",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "sk88"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 6,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] 1 L Le Parfait Jar",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "SLLPJ-6088C959"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 7,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] 1 L Le Parfait Jar",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "SLLPJ-20D88EFC"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 8,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] 1 L Le Parfait Jar",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "SLLPJ-0BAF36BA"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 9,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] 1 L Le Parfait Jar",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "SLLPJ-CD28D4F0"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 10,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] 1 L Le Parfait Jar",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "SLLPJ-9A544946"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 11,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] 1 L Le Parfait Jar",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "SLLPJ-F2FD045F"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 12,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] 1 L Le Parfait Jar",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "SLLPJ-0138EE43"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 13,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] 1 L Le Parfait Jar",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "SLLPJ-D334BA28"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 14,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] 1 L Le Parfait Jar",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "SLLPJ-8650D0FD"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 15,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] 1 L Le Parfait Jar",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "SLLPJ-8D93E1C3"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 16,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "Gorgeous Copper Hat",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "sk94"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 17,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "[Sample] Tiered Wire Basket",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "TWB"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 18,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "Heavy Duty Cotton Gloves",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "sk98"
    },
    {
      "messageId": 19,
      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "Ergonomic Steel Lamp",
            "language_tag": "en_US",
            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
          {
            "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
            "quantity": 10
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "sk103"
    }
  ]
}
```

As can be observed, I am using the product type `SHOES`. In a previous attempt, I had used the product type `LUGGAGE` because that was used in the use-case guides. But Amazon still does not like this. Could someone guide me to a list of valid product types?

Answer (score 4):

I've meet the same issue and solve this one, and I'm just sending https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/definitions/2020-09-01/productTypes?marketplaceIds=A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2 to get the productType is PRODUCT.

You can reference with https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/product-type-definitions-api/definitionsProductTypes_2020-09-01.md#searchdefinitionsproducttypes to find out what is the productType it is in the seller centre without keywords paramters.

Therefore you can try it again using "productType": "PRODUCT".