# Amazon SP API Feeds API processing report: The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, feed, amazon-selling-partner-api

I have been working with the feeds API. I am using a client library in Nodejs. I have been able to create a feed document, encrypt and upload a payload to the returned URL, create the feed, and then check its status in the Amazon Seller Central and also in the json response . Once status reaches the DONE state, I was  able to get the processing report from the seller central: The processing report looks like this:

```
{
    "header": {
        "sellerId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "version": "2.0",
        "feedId": "50013019401"
    },
    "issues": [
        {
            "messageId": 123,
            "code": "4000003",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "message": "The Amazon product type specified is invalid or not supported."
        }
    ],
    "summary": {
        "errors": 1,
        "warnings": 0,
        "messagesProcessed": 1,
        "messagesAccepted": 0,
        "messagesInvalid": 1
    }
}
```

My PlayLoad was this:

```
{
  "header": {
    "sellerId": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "version": "2.0"
  },
  "messages": [
    {
      "messageId": 123,

      "operationType": "UPDATE",
      "productType": "SHOES",
      "requirements": "LISTING",
      "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
          {
            "value": "Awesome shoes",

            "marketplace_id": "A21TJRUUN4KGV"
          }
        ]
      },
      "sku": "abc1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have also try LUGGAGE in the productType because that was used in the use-case guide. But get the same error.
I have also try productType:"PRODUCT" I found this solution in slackOverFlow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68455925/amazon-sp-api-feeds-api-processing-report-invalid-product-type?answertab=trending#tab-top/)
But by try this solution also i am getting an error like this:

```
{
    "header": {
        "sellerId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "version": "2.0",
        "feedId": "50014019401"
    },
    "issues": [
        {
            "messageId": 123,
            "code": "4000004",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "message": "Creating products is not supported with the \"PRODUCT\" Amazon product type. Either specify a specific Amazon product type or specify an offer-only requirements set."
        }
    ],
    "summary": {
        "errors": 1,
        "warnings": 0,
        "messagesProcessed": 1,
        "messagesAccepted": 0,
        "messagesInvalid": 1
    }
}
```

And also can anybody provide me a link where i can find what to fill inside attribute object what are the key value like how to put images,sizes all this thing
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the Product Type Definitions API to determine the correct product type.

[Documentation](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/product-type-api-use-case-guide#:%7E:text=of%20the%20item.-,Tutorial%3A%20Search%20Available%20Product%20Type%20Definitions,-Use%20this%20tutorial)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I have read the documentation but it doesn't help me